# Execute and fetch two queries in the same page

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I have 2 queries in the same PHP file/page when having them like this they work and I get the results.

```
$query1 = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM tableA");
$restult1= mysqli_fetch_assoc($query1);
$query2=  mysqli_query ($link,"SELECT COUNT(id) AS total FROM tableB");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2)){
       echo '<option value="'.$row["id"].'">'.$row["first_name"].' '.$row["last_name"].'</option>';
}
```

But I'm trying to use ***stored procedures*** so when having them like this I only get the result of the first query. I've algo tried to having both queries with stored procedures but it also didn't work.

```
$query1 = mysqli_query($link, "CALL GetUsersAll");
$restult1= mysqli_fetch_assoc($query1);
$query2=  mysqli_query ($link,"SELECT COUNT(id) AS total FROM tableB");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2)){
           echo '<option value="'.$row["id"].'">'.$row["first_name"].' '.$row["last_name"].'</option>';
    }
```

Comment: I beileve this will help you: [multi_query](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_multi_query.asp)

Comment: SP returns two resultsets, you need to call `mysqli_next_result` before the second query: `$restult1= mysqli_fetch_assoc($query1); mysqli_next_result($link); $query2=  mysqli_query ($link,"SELECT COUNT(id) AS total FROM tableB");`

Comment: @A.Cedano thank this worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stored Procedures can returns two or more result sets.

You can to call [`mysqli_next_result`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.next-result.php) before the second query:

```
$query1 = mysqli_query($link, "CALL GetUsersAll");
$restult1= mysqli_fetch_assoc($query1);
mysqli_next_result($link);
$query2=  mysqli_query ($link,"SELECT COUNT(id) AS total FROM tableB");
//... etc
```

But, if you are working with SP from `mysqly` pay attention to the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/apis-php/en/apis-php-mysqli.quickstart.stored-procedures.html):

> ***Handling result sets***
>
> Stored procedures can return result sets. Result sets returned from a
>   stored procedure cannot be fetched correctly using `mysqli_query`. The
>   `mysqli_query` function combines statement execution and fetching the
>   first result set into a buffered result set, if any. However, **there
>   are additional stored procedure result sets hidden from the user which
>   cause `mysqli_query` to fail returning the user expected result
>   sets**.
>
> Result sets returned from a stored procedure are fetched using
>   `mysqli_real_query` or `mysqli_multi_query`. Both functions allow
>   fetching any number of result sets returned by a statement, such as
>   `CALL`. Failing to fetch all result sets returned by a stored
>   procedure causes an error.

You can modify your code as is explained in the [***Example 3.21 Fetching results from stored procedures***](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/apis-php/en/apis-php-mysqli.quickstart.stored-procedures.html)